# ImportError: No module named 'games' when trying to import a module in PyCharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I am learning `Python` using `python programming for the absolute beginner 3rd ed`. Now in `Chapter 9`, When I coded a module called `games` (`games.py` file) in the project root directory, and tried to import it in another file called `simple_game.py` (which is also created in the same directory as `games.py`) using

```
import games
```

`Python` simply stated `ImportError: No module named 'games'`. I am wondering how to solve the issue in `PyCharm` (I am using it to do all the practises with the book).

PS. I am using `Python 3.4.2` on `Win 8.1 X64` with `PyCharm 4.0.4`.

[EDIT] I created another `games.py` by right-clicked the project folder and chose `New->Python File` and copy the code in the old `games.py` to the new one. Run `simple_game` and the import issue was gone. I guess it has something to do with how you create a `python` file in the project? As I usually just right-clicked the project folder and choose `New->File` and `Register New File Type Association` as `Python files`. This way, I found the `python` files in the project folder are unrecognized (shown as `File` for `Type`) if I checked them in the project directory. Also, don't forget to mark project folder as `Sources Root` in order to make the module name reference work.

thanks

Comment: Is `games.py` in the same directory as `simple_game.py`?

Comment: @sweeneyrod yes, I have corrected it in the op. thanks

Comment: Aren't you importing games from livewires? Thus you wouldn't want to use the same module name.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi could you be more specific, I am new to `Python`, don't know what is a livewires.

Comment: Isn't that the framework described in the book?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I think 'livewires' package is introduced in `Chapter 10 - GUI Development`

Comment: How are you running your application?

Comment: @yole If I created `games.py` and `simple_game.py` using `notepad++` and placed them in one folder, while `simple_game` import `games`, I can just double clicked `simple_game` and get it run without problem. But in `PyCharm`, I couldn't. Don't know why.

Comment: How exactly are you running your application in PyCharm? The normal way is to right-click simple_game.py and select "Run simple_game.py" from the context menu.

Comment: @yole usually by pressing `alt+shift+f10` or `shift+f10` in `PyCharm` while `simple_game` is the active tab.